# Pass post variables to next page

Tags: php, html, for-loop

So i basically have a form in html that submits to a preview page, where I access the variables to fill out the information on the page and display a preview of what the post will look like. I now want the user to be able to click a submit button and pass the same info to a new .php page that will handle submitting to database. I'm sure this is probably really easy, forgive me newbishness.

I have a form that submits to something like this and want is so when they click the "all good" button it sends the POST data on to a new .php page that can submit to the database and display a thank you message:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST["preview"])) {

    //get data
    $firstvar = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['name']);
    $nextvar = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['name']);
    //etc
?>
<html> 
//use vars in here
<p><a onclick="goBack()" class="btn btn-block btn-warning">Dont like what you see? Go back and fix it.</a></p>
<p><a href="" class="btn btn-block btn-success">All good!</a></p>

</html>
```

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Ryan Claxton, what you can do is store all your post value in session, on the preview page, now click on the submit button use this session value on the next page where you will store in the database. Once you store in the database release this session variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JiteshNK provided one way of doing it using sessions.

Me, personally, I don't like to waste session variables on trivial things.

So another way you can do this is when you submit to your preview page (let's call `preview.php`), store the values in hidden input fields.

**preview.php**

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["preview"])) {
    // get data
    $var1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['var1']);
    $var2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['var2']);
    // etc
?>

<!-- show vars -->

<form action="insert-page.php">
    <!-- store vars into hidden input fields -->
    <input type="hidden" name="var1" value="<?= $var1 ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="var2" value="<?= $var2 ?>">
    <!-- etc -->
    <p><a onclick="goBack()" class="btn btn-block btn-warning">Dont like what you see? Go back and fix it.</a></p>
    <p><input type="submit" name="good" class="btn btn-block btn-success">All good!</a></p><!-- use submit button instead -->
</form>
```

Comment: Smart. I tend to agree, I would like to avoid a session is at all possible and I like this way. Thank you, good idea.

Comment: @Ryan Claxton , please see the concerns related to hidden fields, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19036081/is-it-more-secure-to-use-a-session-variable-instead-of-a-hidden-input-field

Answer (score 0):

Here is the below code.

```
<?php
include('connect.php');//connect.php is the connection file.
if(isset($_POST['submit']))//Here submit is the name of the form in HTML page.
{
    $user_id=$_POST['user_id'];
    $username=$_POST['username'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $query = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO sample (user_id, username, email)VALUES ('$user_id', '$username', '$email')");
    header('Location: activation.php');
}
else
{
    echo "<b>Error</b>";
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Thank you, I know how to do that part. Im just wondering how i get my info from a preview page to that submit page. (its for a post not user sign up). To clarify a user fills out a form that will turn into a post. They have an option to click a preview button that sends them to a preview page similar to what I have above.. and if they like the preview I want them to be able to click submit and do something like what you have up there.. I just dont know how to forward the $_POST info from the preview page to the submit page. THanks.